# Haskell Foldr C implementation

Tags: c, haskell

I'm trying to implement a version of Haskell's foldr function in C but have hit a wall making it generic as I want to make the + or * characters (char y in foldr) work as addition or multiplication. I was thinking of trying a macro but wasn't sure what would work.

Here the code:

```
int
foldr(int *v, int (*f)(int*), int x, char y)
{
    int temp;
    if(*v == (int) NULL) //v is null terminated int array
        return x;
    else{
        temp = *v;
        return temp y ((*f)(++v));
    }
}
```

Main issue is making char y work so I can say:

```
int
sum(int *v)
{
    return foldr(v, (sum), 0, '+');
}
```

and it would just work.
Thanks

Comment: Try a switch on y and case '+' do addition and case '*' do multiplication

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to call it as : `foldr(v, 0, '+')` and it would work?

Comment: Wow, there's a lot wrong with this. `*v == (int) NULL` is almost certainly not what you want. No idea what `temp y ((*f)(++v))` is supposed to mean. Why is there an `int (*)(int*)` argument to `foldr`? Presumably this is supposed to be the function to fold, but doesn't appear to be a function that takes a list element and an accumulator as is usually the case for `foldr`. And if `f` is the function to fold, what is the `char y` argument supposed to be? In its current state, this appears to me to be just "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, I thought I'd made y clear with the snippet of sum as trying to make this foldr to be as generic as possible. int (*)(int*) comes from the way I was using Null terminated arrays and recursion to build the function. You're right though I do need to think this through again. Thank you

Comment: You can treat `int *` as a 0-terminated or (-1)-terminated array-ish, but that would mean that 0 (or -1) can't be valid data. Consider passing both a pointer and the array length, instead. `f` should be binary, as it is in `foldr`. Or, even better, make it ternary, taking an additional `void *` pointer to emulate closures, mimicking what some C libraries do for callbacks (see e.g. GTK).

Comment: (+) and (\*) in Haskell are *functions*, not characters.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show a recursion-based approach. As an exercise, you could turn it into an iterative solution, if you wish.

(Warning: untested)

Haskell:

```
foldr :: (Int->Int->Int) -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
foldr f x []     = x                    -- base case
foldr f x (v:vs) = f v (foldr f x vs)   -- recursion
```

C:

```
int foldr(int (*f)(int,int),
          int x,
          int *v, size_t length) {
    // base case
    if (length == 0) return x;
    // recursion
    return f(*v, foldr(f, x, v+1, length-1));
}
```

Test:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
   return a+b;
}
int main() {
   int a[] = {1,2,3} ;
   int res = foldr(add, 0, a, sizeof a/sizeof *a);
   printf("%d\n", res);
   return 0;
}
```

If you pass a proper function pointer (like `add`) above, there is not need to pass the character operator `'+'`.

---

Note that functional programming languages also allow to build closures, as in:

```
let y = 5
in foldr (\x c -> x*y+c) 0 [1..3]
```

Note how the function `\x c -> x*y+c` also depends on the value of `y`. C does not allow to do craft closures, but you can emulate the captured `y`, if you allow an addition `void *` argument to the C function.

```
int foldr(int (*f)(void *, int, int),
          void *data,
          int x,
          int *v, size_t length) {
    // base case
    if (length == 0) return x;
    // recursion
    return f(data, *v, foldr(f, data, x, v+1, length-1));
}
```

Test:

```
int g(void *data, int x, int c) {
   int y = *(int *)data;
   return x*y+c;
}
int main() {
   int a[] = {1,2,3} ;
   int y = 5;
   int res = foldr(g, &y, 0, a, sizeof a/sizeof *a);
   printf("%d\n", res);
   return 0;
}
```

In this way you can reuse `g` with different values of `y`. If you need to capture more variables, pass a pointer to a suitable `struct` containing all such variables.

Comment: Thanks for this, it really showed me that I was trying to force C to work like Haskell rather than transposing Haskell code to C as you've done.

Comment: @SilasPoulson Keep in mind that transposing code like this from one language to another does not produce idiomatic code. It can still be interesting. The above approach is not something one would use in everyday C.